# AngularJS UI-Router, resolve $http dependency is lost upon minify

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, angular-ui, minify

I'm trying to resolve some data before the controller get's loaded. Works as expected on development code, but when I minify it, my `$http` get's replaced by `e` or whatever variable is available.

I can't inject `$http` in the `angular.module("app", []).config`. So I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
angular.module("app", [
  "app.controllers"
  "app.directives"
  "app.filters"
  "app.services"
]).config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

  $stateProvider.state("tab",
    url: "/tab"
    abstract: true
    templateUrl: "tpls/tabs.html"
  )

  .state("tab.programs",
    url: "/programs"
    abstract: true
    resolve:
      events: ($http) -> # $http get's replaced upon minification..
        $http.get('my.example.site/events.json')
          .then((data) ->
            data.data
          )
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok I've figured it out.

I have to inject it on the function itself. Like this:

```
  .state("tab.programs",
    url: "/programs"
    abstract: true
    resolve:
      events: ['$http', ($http) -> # $http now is injected
        $http.get('my.example.site/events.json')
          .then((data) ->
            data.data
          )
        ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Coffeescript makes my brain hurt, but in Javascript you'd do

```
config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {

   ...

}]);
```

That is, an `array` containing your all dependencies as `strings` (in order) and then the `function` to run.

The minimizer won't mess with the strings, and Angular's DI framework understands that syntax.

Comment: As a little rant, I don't understand why so many tutorials and examples are not using that syntax. I understand the point about it being harder to read but having the minifier screw people over later down the road is not cool.

Comment: That doesn't work. I've tried to inject `$http` but that gives me an 
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dat due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $http`

Comment: Ah, I misread then, I thought the problem was already in the config-function. You can use the same syntax in the resolve-block.

Comment: But I'm surprised that the `config` dependencies survived minifaction.

Comment: thats because I was using https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ngmin
;)
So I did not have to care about it.